# Automatically move to next line in Collection View Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to achieve ordering in collection view like in Inbox by Gmail.

[image: Screenshot]

The problem is that I couldn't find already implemented library like RecyclerView.

Is it any implemented Collection View which has such behaviour?

Comment: just use `staggered gridview` with recycler view

Comment: Great, could you write example though?